# ColdFusion Script Passing 2 variables

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to return two variables in a ColdFusion function.

I know you can do this in C++ using the & sign.

my code:

```
<cfscript>

function browserDetect(browser,version) {

      browser="some value string";
      version="some other value string";
}
</cfscript>
```

other page:

```
<cfoutput>#BrowserName# and #BrowserVer#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The & sign in C++ is a pointer, something ColdFusion doesn't support on primative values like strings. Phantom42's answer is the right thing to do in ColdFusion. You may be able to shorten it slightly by using the struct literal syntax.

Comment: FYI the & sign is to denote a reference, not a pointer in C++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My preferred method is to return back a struct with the appropriate key/value pairs.

```
<cfscript>

    function browserDetect(arg1,arg2) {
      var resultStruct = structNew() ;
      resultStruct.browser="some value string";
      resultStruct.version="some other value string";

      return resultStruct ;
    }
</cfscript>
```

Instead of creating a local struct, you could also return back the results using an explicit struct

```
return { browser : "some value string" , version : "some other value string" }
```

Set `resultVar` to the results of your function and then you would then just output using

```
<cfoutput>#resultvar.browser# and #resultVar.version#</cfoutput>
```

You could also create a JSON string and return that back .

Comment: You should add that `return { browser : "some value string" , version : "some other value string" }` is a convenient shorthand.

Comment: **It's not implicit**! :( It is _explicit_ struct literal notation. (If you really want an i-word, it can be called an inline struct.)